# How to update a record in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, fetch, react-native-ios

I am using firebase to store my data. When I am adding or getting data, there is no problem. But I can't update an existing report. For example, I have notes. And user can open a note, edit and save. On save, it should save the changes on existing record. But I can't do that.

Here is how I tried.

```
fetch('https://shared-places-***.firebaseio.com/notes.json/' + this.state.updatedNote,{
      method:'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          Header: this.state.newNoteHeader,
          Explanation: this.state.newNoteSub,
          Date: new Date(),
      })
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I have added my id to request link hoping I directly effect it but it didn't work. Also tried changing method to Update but also didn't work of course. I have searched but couldn't find an answer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer that I was making small mistakes. First of all, method should be `PUT` not `POST`. Also address should be `https://shared-places-***.firebaseio.com/notes/' + this.state.updatedNote + '.json'`